# How can I print "System Generated Log" in a log file using log4j2x in Selenium JAVA and TestNG?

Tags: java, selenium, log4j2

### **System Generate Log looks like this**

```
15:38:09,447 DEBUG RequestAddCookies:122 - CookieSpec selected: default
15:38:09,456 DEBUG RequestAuthCache:76 - Auth cache not set in the context
15:38:09,459 DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:249 - Connection request: [route: {}->http://localhost:35155][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2000; total allocated: 0 of 2000]
15:38:09,471 DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:282 - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {}->http://localhost:35155][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2000; total allocated: 1 of 2000]
15:38:09,473 DEBUG MainClientExec:234 - Opening connection {}->http://localhost:35155
15:38:09,474 DEBUG DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator:131 - Connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:35155
15:38:09,475 DEBUG DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator:138 - Connection established 127.0.0.1:61877<->127.0.0.1:35155
15:38:09,475 DEBUG DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection:90 - http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 10800000
15:38:09,475 DEBUG MainClientExec:255 - Executing request POST /session HTTP/1.1
15:38:09,475 DEBUG MainClientExec:260 - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
15:38:09,476 DEBUG MainClientExec:266 - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
15:38:09,477 DEBUG headers:135 - http-outgoing-0 >> POST /session HTTP/1.1
15:38:09,477 DEBUG headers:138 - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

**I want to print it in a log file using log4j2x**

Comment: what is "System Generate Log"?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the actual definition. But I think when you run the code Selenium do some stuff it the background to do the automation things those are "System Generated Log" I guess. You can visit this website https://www.guru99.com/tutorial-on-log4j-and-logexpert-with-selenium.html and you will get a kind of idea. It's working on log4j1x

Answer (score 0):

In Log4j2.xml file please mention parameter as **AppenderRef ref="File"** instead of **AppenderRef ref="Console"**

Please refer to the below Log4j2.xml configuration settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
       <Properties>
<Property name="basePath">./logs</Property>
</Properties>
 
  <Appenders>
      <RollingFile name="File" fileName="${basePath}/prints.log" filePattern="${basePath}/prints-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
     <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
      <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500" />
          </RollingFile>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Also, please refer [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.1/manual/configuration.html) for more details

Comment: I know that it will only give you the "Application Log" that you type on your code.
But I want to achieve this. 
https://www.guru99.com/tutorial-on-log4j-and-logexpert-with-selenium.html
But it used log4j1x I want to do that in log4j2x

Answer (score 0):

Yes all the selenium log can be generated along with application logs. If you want to use log4j.properties file then I have a solution. You can use below settings in the file:(first block to capture all selenium logs and second one for application logs).

```
#Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=debug,file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=F:\\seleniumworkspaces\\LiveProjects\\PageObjectwithFactories\\src\\test\\resources\\logs\\selenium.log
log4j.appender.file.maxFileSize=5000KB
log4j.appender.file.maxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.Append=false



#Application Logs
log4j.logger.devpinoyLogger=DEBUG, dest1
log4j.appender.dest1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dest1.maxFileSize=5000KB
log4j.appender.dest1.maxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.dest1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dest1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c %m%n
log4j.appender.dest1.File=F:\\seleniumworkspaces\\LiveProjects\\PageObjectwithFactories\\src\\test\\resources\\logs\\application.log
log4j.appender.dest1.Append=false
```